# Этимологические родственники

Tags: этимология

Являются ли этимологически родственными слова: графин и графиня, кувшин и кувшинка, чайка и чайник, банка и банк, тарелка и тара?

Answer (score 1):

Кувшин и кувшинка; банка и банк (если банка — доска для сидения гребцов в лодке).